# File inclusion check bypass

Tags: file-inclusion

The following function is used to protect from arbitrary file download:-

```
function file_download($file_name, $file_path) {
    $allowedExtensions = array(
            "csv"
            );
    $checkFileName = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$file_name);
    $extension = explode(".",$file_name);
    end($extension);
    if (file_exists($file_path) && count($checkFileName) == 1 && in_array(strtolower($extension[key($extension)]),$allowedExtensions)) {
            readfile($file_path);
            exit ;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Please help bypass the usage is like follows:-

```
file_download($_GET['file_name'], "path".$_GET['file_name']);
```

Comment: Is this for a CTF or homework? Because the code doesn't make much sense; `$file_name` isn't actually used.

Comment: It's a production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would simply set **$file_name** to **passwd.csv** and **file_path** to **/etc/passwd**.

Comment: actually, I had posted with an error the question above is edited. Please have a look.